# Multiple application android:name tags in manifest caused by Configuration my app for multidex

Tags: android, manifest

first I'm just a beginner, I'm using android studio and I try to import an Eclipse project, I get this:

> "Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed
>   64K"

I try to solve it but I get a duplicate attribute name, is there a way to fix it?

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name=".App" android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:theme">
```

> Error:L'attribut "name" lié à l'espace de noms "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" a déjà été spécifié pour l'élément "application".

Answer (score 1):

You must have only one `android:name` entry, which error message clearly tells you about. Not sure what you wanted to achieve by adding this:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

but if that's your way of doing inheritance, then it's wrong and must be removed. You need to have one `android:name` pointing to your application class subclass. If you do not provide custom application class then remove all `android:name` from your `<application>`

Answer (score 0):

Try remove this from manifest file:

```
android:name=".App"
```

So your code be like this:

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:theme">
```